# IDE tools for Flash/ActionScript swf creation

Tags: actionscript-3, ide

I am not a Flash/ActionScript developer but I need to achieve a very small task in Flash. I need to display user audio input level in Flash. I found that I can do that using ActionScript ([according to this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d0c.html)).

I have no idea what tools I need to use and generate a SWF file.
Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Flash Pro IDE  (eg Flash CS6),  Flash Builder (Adobe),  or FlashDevelop.  There are also a few more like FDT and IntelliJ.

If this is a quick and dirty no/low budget scenario for you, I would recommend FlashDevelop.

If speed is of the utmost importance and you don't have time to learn, then Flash Pro CS~ would be a good bet.

If you're an experienced coder and will be using the tool a fair bit, Flash Builder (as a commercial product) is a good bet. Though FlashDevelop is also a good open source alternative to Flash Builder.

They all have tutorials on their websites on how to get your environment setup and start creating swfs.

http://www.flashdevelop.org/

http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder.html

http://www.adobe.com/products/flash.html

http://fdt.powerflasher.com/

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Comment: IntelliJ is another IDE that can be used for development of Flash Platform/Flex applications.

Comment: If you don't have a *budget* consideration, **I would recommend Flash Builder**. As a developer I feel totally comfortable with it since it is built on top of Eclipse. If you don't want to buy a tool then head to **FlashDevelop**.